# Setup pi before first boot

Tags: raspbian, boot, image

I was wondering whether it was technically possible to install wireless connections for WiFi and Bluetooth (f.ex on a raspberry pi 3) before burning the image to the micro SD card.
So you would manipulate the (raspbian) image before you insert the SD card into your Pi.

Answer (score 2):

I know it's possible for Wi-Fi. You need to mount the SD card and edit `/etc/network/interfaces`.

You should edit the file to look something like this:

```
auto lo 
iface lo inet loopback
iface eth0 inet dhcp 

allow-hotplug wlan0
auto wlan0 iface 

wlan0 inet dhcp
    wpa-ssid "SSID" 
    wpa-psk "password"
```

Fill in your SSID and password (keep the quotes!)

Comment: Thank you for the response. But I was actually wondering whether I could edit before mounting (so I can burn multiple SD cards for multiple pi's without needing a screen or a lan cable to connect them to the network.

Comment: Or did I misunderstood what you meant with "mount the SD-card"?

Comment: I mean you need to mount the SD on your laptop/pc. Then edit the interface file, unmount and put in in your Rpi.

Comment: You can also create an image of the modified SD card and burn multiple SD cards.

Comment: If you are going to try this do not use the obsolete settings above, which will break GUI networking and will not automatically restart WiFi. See http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/37921/8697 for settings.